# Remove responses from Responses tab once they've been read in Inbox

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, profile-page, global-inbox, responses

Whenever we get a new response, it appears in both the Inbox (the red icon) and the Response tab in the profile (the blue notification). If we view the response from the Inbox, the notification gets cleared there but not in the Response tab (and conversely).

So it would be nice if, once we read read the responses either in the tab or the Inbox, it gets cleared from both places. Otherwise I often find myself opening the Response tab just to find that I've already read all these "new" answers.

Comment: I ignore the Responses tab, myself. I wish it didn't show the number of "new" responses, it's just annoying.

Comment: I don't ignore the "responses" tab as @Matthew does (in some rare cases I find it useful), but indeed I ignore the _number_ of "new" responses, which is not helpful whatsoever.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The responses tab and inbox show slightly different data.

The inbox doesn't include revisions, and the responses tab only shows activity on the current site.  Viewing either clearing the unread count on the other would be incorrect.