# Can the reply notifications be synced as read once read?

Tags: feature-request, notifications

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [The StackExchange™ MultiCollider SuperDropdown™ says I've got replies, but I've already viewed those](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67987/the-stackexchange-multicollider-superdropdown-says-ive-got-replies-but-ive-a)

On little thing that has been bothering me from some time now, and taking up quite a bit of my interaction on the site, has been getting notifications to turn off once I read them.

When someone replies to me I get a notification of the event in these places:

1. Top left "Stack Exchange"
2. User page
3. The comment itself.

So let's take this use case for example: I comment on someone's answer and they reply back soon after. I read the comment on the page and reply to it. Then I take care of the red (1) by the stack exchange button. It takes me to the same comment, and then I got to my account and take care of the comment there.

I'd love for it to update all notifications as read when I read the comment (or if I load the page the comment is on)

Comment: +1 for this... huge timesaver for someone who's a bit obsessive about clearing notifications (like me).

Comment: Part of this request has [already been `status-declined`](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/67987), and there's an [existing request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/102153) for the rest.